# PHP KeepAlive program for Amazon

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, keep-alive

So im fairly new to PHP and i was assigned a small project by my manager, now my problem is that this is the first time doing anything like this so was wondering for some advice, guidance, help in any shape or form just as abit of a leg up,

So here's the description,

PROBLEM

Amazon EC2 can have multiple instances running behind a load balancer.

The load balancer will check at a URL i.e /_healthcheck to verify if the machine is functional.

The term functional can be defined as

- Webserver can be accessed (implied by ability to connect to this check)
- Webserver can connect to network resources CouchDB and Elastic Search
- The node is not experiencing extremely high loads currenty(?)

Create a MVC for AWS EC2 to verify that the node is online

so far this is what code i've wrote, confused on how to satisfy time requirements for PHP (e.g check every 5 seconds etc)

```
class KeepaliveController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function statusAction() {
        $host = 'http://localhost:8089';
        $port = 80;
        $waitTime = 0;
        $attempt = 1;
        if($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTime)){
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        } elseif ($waittime > 5){
            echo "server busy retrying";
            $response = $this->getResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(503);


        elseif ($attempt > 5){
            echo "Internal Error";
            $response = $this ->getResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(500)
            $attempt++      
        } else {
            echo "server offline";
            $reponse = $this->getResponse();
            $reponse->setStatusCode(404);
        }
    }
```

as i said any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Surely the time requirement is defined when you set your health check on the load balancer? You define how reqularly you want it to run against each node serviced by that load balancer

Comment: Why are you setting the `fsockopen()` timeout to 0 seconds?

Comment: yes changed it now thank you for the input, was missing a few syntax error's as well, my main query is how to do the rest of the errors i mean here i have the big 3 in reality but there's a ton more i think i need to do :)

Comment: What actually runs on port 8089? Is that CouchDB?

Comment: its the healthcheck website, couch db is on port localhost:5984, after reading the first comment i think the wait time will be handled by the amazon load balance so i'll just keep it as it is atm, im more confused on what requirements a say 300 error has, like 404 is no response 500 is 5 attempts so ye :) again thank you for your help